# .map Returning its not function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, mern

I have a mern application using redux for state management.

For some reason when I try to map through it, it tells me it's not a function.

It is weird because when I see my props through the console, it shows me it's an array and react knows that I have data in my state. And it also shows the data in my redux dev tools. But when I try to render it gives me that error. Also when i do this.props.products.products it tells me cannot read property of Null.
Here's the github repo
https://github.com/bryanb213/seller

Can anyone explain why

stuff.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './stuff.stle.css'
import { getProducts } from '../redux/actions/productActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';



class Stuff extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getProducts();
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Products from props', this.props)

        if (this.props.loading === true) {
            return (
                <div>Loading...</div >
            )
        } else {
            return(
                <div>
                    { this.props.products.map(p => (
                            <h1>{p.name}</h1>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    //products from root reducer
    products: state.products,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProducts })(Stuff);
```

Action

```
// Get all products
export const getProducts = () => dispatch => {
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:5000/api/products/all')
        .then(res =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_PRODUCTS,
                payload: res.data
            })
        )
        .catch(err =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_PRODUCTS,
                payload: null
            })
        );
};
```

Reducer

```
import { GET_PRODUCTS } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    products: null,
    loading: true
}

export default function(state= initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_PRODUCTS:
            console.log('hitting GET_PRODUCTS', action.payload)
            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Server route

```
router.get('/all', (req, res) => {
    Product.find()
        .exec()
        .then(stuff => {
            res.status(200).json(stuff);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
});
```

[image]
[postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hepca.png)

Comment: It looks like the array is `this.props.products.products`

Comment: Sorry for not stating this before but when I do that it tells me cannot read property of Null

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {
    console.log("Products from props", this.props);
    const { loading, products } = this.props;
    if (loading === true) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>{products && products.products.map(p => <h1>{p.name}</h1>)}</div>
      );
    }
  }
```

`this.props.products` value is `{ products : [..] }`, so you have to access it by `this.props.products.products`, in cases like this it will be easier if you use destructring assignment syntax to get the respected values to avoid some confusion.

Comment: it tells me cannot read property of Null I also thought this was the case but I don't get the data back if I map that far deep

Comment: can you add the full structure of your object?

Comment: I added my reducer where I set the data in the object and the response from my server in Postman(Sorry about my reducer before I didn't realize I pasted the action twice)